# What's the best agile toolchain for Qt?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm curious if anyone else has a good recommendation for a Qt friendly toolchain.

We're currently evaluating using The following:

- Bug/Issue Tracking - Atlassian JIRA (already in use)
- IDE - Qt Creator (already in use)
- Code Coverage - gcov (are there easy ways to integrate this into the dev/CI environment?)
- Unit Testing - QTestLib and Boost Test
- Code Review  - Either Atlassian Crucible (expensive) or ReviewBoard (free)
- Nightly build/check-in build - Hudson, CruisControl or Atlassian Bamboo. Any advice?
- Code Analysis/Style Checker - Vera++? CppCheck? Any suggestions?
- Source Code monitoring - Atlassian Fisheye (only if we go with Crucible), ViewVC. Any advice?

Are there any other tools I should take a look at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bugs: Bugzilla

IDE: QtCreator but many people will hate you if you *enforce* the use of one ide over the other, specially if you have opensource developers.

Code Coverage: In order to use gcov for code coverage, your ci environment needs to build the software with appropriate set of flags and *execute* the code. Also do note that gcov itself does not do any reporting, you need something like lcov to then actually generate the statistics from gcov generated files.

NightlyBuilds:  TeamCity, but if you have time to invest and you do want flexbility: BuildBot.

CodeReview: Review board is quite good.

Comment: I totally disagree to your _Bugs: Bugzilla_ statement!
Nothing is worse than Bugzilla.

Comment: I prefer [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) or [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview)(Not free but cheap) and for Code Review: [Gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/)

Answer (score 1):

A .pro based build framework will allow your developers to use their own preferred IDE

AQtime is a decent profiler and leak checker

SourceMonitor provides some nice metrics

Comment: SourceMonitor seems pretty useful. Thanks for that one!
It's unclear from the AQtime website's initial page that it works with C++ Here's a place they do mention it: http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/supported-dev-tools/

Any other tips?

Comment: AQtime supports C++, contact their support department for more info, but be warned, they have very thorough salesmen!